# Is it possible to define atomic chunks of math which automatically do line breaks when necessary?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, align, amsmath, line-breaking

I'm writing a paper for a journal, which publishes in double column style, but the submitted manuscript has to be single-column. This means, I have to make sure that the formulas are properly formatted for both variants. The challenging thing here is, that in double column style the horizontal space is far smaller than in single column. So one possibility would be to manually break all formulas such that they fit the double column style. However, this has the disadvantage that they would look strangely formatted in the single column manuscript. What is the best practice to solve this?

I'm aware of the two packages `breqn` and `autobreak`, which however both do not work properly (to my knowledge). Loading `breqn` immediately breaks my whole document (build fails even if I do not use it anywhere). Loading `autobreak` works, but the "autobreak" environment creates errors.

What I basically want is an environment where I can put atomic parts of my equation into, which are then automatically arranged either in a single line or in multiple lines, depending on how much horizontal space is available, like I used the hypothetical `chunk`-environment here:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    \begin{chunk} % <--
    f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,
    \end{chunk}   % <--
    \begin{chunk} % <--
    f\left(x\right) = 2x
    \end{chunk}   % <--
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Depending on the amount of horizontal space available, I want this code to either produce

[image]

or

[image]

Does something like this exist? If not, what else are the best practices?

Comment: In a similar position I just made everything work for a two-column layout and the reviewers had to deal with tall narrow equations on the submitted version.  Even reviewer 2 didn't complain about that

Comment: Hello, I tried getting automatic line breaking to work (for display math) generally a long time ago, and realized that this was extremely difficult. I think it's better to do it manually. Best of luck, should you decide to proceed with this goal. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this has any hope of working in a general sense, but I was able to make it work in this limited example.  In particular, one has to think how they would like something like `aligned` to work when the margin gets too small...I'm not sure an obvious answer presents itself.  Nonetheless, I have provided an EDIT that may provide a first stab at handling it.

I created a `breakable` environment, which (in this example), I called inside of `gather`, which will be applying the equation label in the normal way.  `breakable` creates a `[b]`-aligned minipage of `\linewidth` minus some delta to allow for the tag width.  The delta is an optional argument to `breakable`.  The environment sets up inline math in the minipage, centered, `\onehalfspacing`, sloppy, and in `\displaystyle`.

Content in the environment can be set in `\chunk{}` macros, which itself is set in an unbreakable box (an optional argument can set the math style).  `\allowbreak` is called after setting the box, to allow for additional line-breakability.

For things that need to break within a portion of the full `\linewidth`, such as one side of a long `align`, I have tried to deal with that by way of the `interbreakable` environment, which has a similar argument syntax to `breakable`.  However, here, the minipage is raggedright and top-aligned.  Furthermore, the optional dimensional argument should account not just for the tag width, but also the width of the other portion of the line which is not part of the `interbreakable` environment (Therefore, it generally needs an increase beyond the default, see discussion at end).

In the MWE, I don't use `\chunk`s inside of `interbreakable`, only because the terms are short enough to preclude a line break at a wrong spot.  However, it should work, if needed (I think).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,setspace,environ}
\newcommand\chunk[2][\displaystyle]{\sbox0{$#1#2$}\box0\allowbreak}
\newenvironment{breakable}[1][30pt]
{\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1}\sloppy\centering
  \onehalfspacing$\displaystyle}
{$\end{minipage}}
\NewEnviron{interbreakable}[1][30pt]{
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\displaystyle\BODY$}%
  \ifdim\wd2 > \dimexpr\linewidth-#1\relax\wd2=\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\relax\fi
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\wd2}\sloppy\raggedright
  \onehalfspacing$\displaystyle\BODY$\end{minipage}}
%\textwidth=1.5in
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Here is my first equation:
\begin{gather}
\begin{breakable}
    \chunk{f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,}\quad
    \chunk{f\left(x\right) = 2x}
\end{breakable}
\end{gather}
And now, for the even more complicated next equation,
\begin{gather}
\begin{breakable}
    \chunk{f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,}\quad
    \chunk{f\left(x\right) = 2x^2 + 3x,} \text{ and }
    \chunk{f'\left(0\right) = 0}
\end{breakable}
\end{gather}
Look, Mom!! I can do align after a fashion.
\begin{align}
  y &= \begin{interbreakable}[60pt]m_1x^3 + m_2x^2 
    + m_3x + b\end{interbreakable}\\
  E &= \begin{interbreakable}[60pt]mc^2 + \strut\log (ac) 
    - \int_0^1 x\,dx\end{interbreakable}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the smaller `\textwidth` uncommented:

[image]

To study the effect of the optional argument on `interbreakable`, the MWE uses `60pt` in Eq 3.  If I set it too small, let's say `40pt`, the equation gets wider and crowds out the tag, which has to shift downward:

[image]

If I make it too big, let's say `80pt`, then it makes the available space for the environment too narrow and breaks more often than needed:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this which produces one of these two layouts depending on
the line width.  Note this is coded as a document level choice not a measurement on each
expression.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass
[twocolumn]
{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ifdim\linewidth<250pt
  \let\zaligned\aligned
  \let\endzaligned\endaligned
\else
   \def\zaligned{\,\let\\=\relax}
   \def\endzaligned{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{zaligned}
    f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\\
    f\left(x\right) = 2x
\end{zaligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to change this code such that it produces a `\qquad` in the first case, where there is a line break in the second case?

Answer (score 3):

`autobreak` can be used for this specific example if you insert `\MoveEqLeft[0]` as the first "chunk" (note that in the `autobreak` environment chunk boundaries are represented as line breaks):

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

Full width:
\begin{align}
  \begin{autobreak}
    \MoveEqLeft[0]
    f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \qquad
    f\left(x\right) = 2x
  \end{autobreak}
\end{align}

3\,cm:\\
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\begin{align}
  \begin{autobreak}
    \MoveEqLeft[0]
    f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \qquad
    f\left(x\right) = 2x
  \end{autobreak}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Disclosure: I am the author of `autobreak`.